# Do weapon upgrades work on shooting range?

Tags: the-evil-within-2

I'm having troubles getting all the rewards on shooting range.

For main game I've mostly spent weapon parts to upgrade shotgun, and I was thinking on getting my handgun upgraded just to beat these shooting challenges.

Do handgun upgrades work on shooting range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the handgun upgrades will be active and assist you in the shooting range.

It is a while since I played but I remember not being able to complete all the shooting challenges initially, however I was able to complete them far more easily once I had upgraded the handgun later in the game.